# Pow server suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, pow, rack-pow

As the title says, Pow just stopped working today. I simply get "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to app.dev" when visiting the app.dev or IP address directly.

**curl: (7) couldn't connect to host**

### Details

MacOS 10.8
/Users/iMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby

#### powder config

bin          /Users/iMac/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/bin/pow
dstPort      88
httpPort     20559
dnsPort      20560
timeout      900
workers      2
domains      dev
extDomains
hostRoot     /Users/iMac/Library/Application Support/Pow/Hosts
logRoot      /Users/iMac/Library/Logs/Pow
rvmPath      /Users/iMac/.rvm/scripts/rvm

#### powder status

pid          3005
version      0.4.1
requestCount 5

#### Pow log

Doesn't show any recent activity.

### What I've tried so far

- Rebooting
- Restarting/Re-installing pow
- Trying this [bash script](http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2011/12/23/restarting-pow-when-dns-stops-responding/)
- Disabling chrome auto DNS thing in chrome://flags
- Trying with Safari and Firefox

The only thing that I can think of is the most recent AirPort update.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

[*See open issue on github for possible updates*](https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/404)